# Weird margin in a list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to style a menu, but I keep running into this weird margin that's appearing in both FF4 and IE.

This is the only affecting css:

```
#header ul
{
  display: inline;
}
#header ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
#header ul li a
{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
  <div id="header">
    <ul id="toplinks">
      <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Herp</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Derp</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[image: screenshot] 
As you can see, there's a margin appearing on both sides, and I'd like it so it would have no margin (or maybe 1px would be okay)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no moon...i mean...margin.

What you're seeing is the white space between your elements. Inline-block treats the elements as inline, except they have heights, widths, margins, paddings, etc. What happens is the newline + spacing you've given your html elements for nice indentation is being displayed as a space between the elements.

inline-block is also not cross-browser consistent. I'd suggest using `display:block;` with floats.

Edit to add suggestion:

If you want nice indents, but want to avoid extra white-space (as in all XML data ever), use what I call the "fishy notation"

Instead of:

```
<div id="header">
 <ul id="toplinks">
  <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Herp</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Derp</a></li>
</ul>
```

Use:

```
<div id="header"
  ><ul id="toplinks"
    ><li><a href="#">Hello</a></li
    ><li><a href="#">Herp</a></li
    ><li><a href="#">Derp</a></li
  ></ul
></div>
```

White space *contained by* elements is preserved, but white space **within** elements is ***not***.

Comment: I've had this happen to me before (where newlines & indents give me spacing issues -_-). Thanks though!

Comment: If you do want to retain formatting, then set the container's font size to 0 and then reapply normal font size to the children.

Comment: I love the "fishy notation", it solved a problem I had been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the last half hour! Thanks soooooo much! +1

Answer (score 1):

Time to whip out that [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)! I first include this, and then start designing. It makes it much easier, as most HTML will look identical cross-browser.

But to fix your problem, I would check if there is a stray border property somewhere. I've had rogue borders before, and they drove me mad. To kill it (for now), try this:

```
border-style: none;
```

If we had the *complete* CSS (don't worry, we don't steal it), I could actually fiddle with it and give you a fully functional answer.

Comment: That's pretty much all the CSS, aside from a few hovers and a few others. I tried using CSS reset, as well as applying the border-style to the li's, and even tried * { border-style: none; }, but it didn't seem to work. I guess I don't mind floating left (for now). ;) Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS to

```
#header ul
{
  display: inline;
}
#header ul li
{
  float:left;
  background: #000;
  margin-left: 1px;;
  padding: 0; 
}
#header ul li a
{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why? I'm not doubting your validity, but a clearer and less offensive answer would be nice too ;)

Comment: Meh, that will do, even though it changes the initial layout a bit.